# Do I need to have unnecessary variables in a object so that i could extract all the needed data from a REST call?

Tags: hibernate, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I am making a spring boot server with a database using a many to many relationship + extra columns in it.

The structure of it is this:

[image]

Lets say I want to add a new order to the database through a REST call. So I am getting an order object from a client that contains a list of products and for each product the amount of it that is ordered. How should i extract the list of products and ordered amount from the object? Do i have to add a list of products and orderedAmount variable in order object even if those already exist in other objects and are connected in database? Or is it a better practice to change the type of REST call that the client is making? Also how should I construct the json object that I am sending, should it be something of type:

```
{
  "orderproducts": [
    {
      "product": 1,
      "orderedAmount": 58
    },
    {
      "product": 2,
      "orderedAmount":32
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't add unnecessary variables.

Secondly, make your client send a json similar to below.
With the assumption that you already have the products in your database. If the products do not exist in your database then the client needs to send the data for fields required to create a new product instead of the id

1 order json

```
{
  'orderDate': '03/01/2020',
  'products': [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'orderedAmount': 12
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "orderedAmount":32
    }
  ]
}
```

many orders json

```
[
  {
    'orderDate': '03/01/2020',
    'products': [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'orderedAmount': 12
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "orderedAmount":32
      }
    ]
  }, 
  {
    'orderDate': '04/01/2020',
    'products': [
      {
        'id': 100,
        'orderedAmount': 10
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Lastly, after you receive the data

- Create a new order with the orderDate if required.
- Get the product(s) using the id / or create new product(s) using
  product data.
- Use the id of the newly created order, id of the product(s), and
  their respective orderAmounts to populate the order_product